# HTML/CSS/JS desktop application runtime for RHEL6

Tags: desktop-application, redhat, node-webkit, rhel, rhel6

I have a software user interface built with node-webkit, which works great for most platforms. However, on RedHat Linux 6 OS Chromium is not supported, and node.js requires some hacky methods that I shouldn't be allowed to automate for other companies' nodes.

This is because RHEL6 has locked glibc version to 2.12 and [the gtk version to 2.18](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/684).

Basically, I'd really like to avoid having to build an entire new UI (in a different language than HTML/CSS/JS) just for RHEL6 users. Is there a desktop runtime such as node-webkit for RHEL6 that I could use as a base for the front end of my software?